# Validate SSH connectivity using SSH-keys

Tags: bash, security, ssh, ip

I have connected two servers using SSH key exchange. Now I am able to login into remote server without password.

Now , I want to validate if connection is really working without password .How can I do that ?

I tried following approach where SSH should timeout after 10 seconds,  I will capture its Return code. but it never does. Once it timeout. It remain on the password prompt.

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -o ConnectTimeout=15 user@ip.ip.ip.ip exit

if [ "$?" -ne 0 ];then
  echo "SSH keys no more working,you need to initiate keys exchange again!!"
  exit 1;
fi
```

## Case-I

However,when SSH keys are not working then and it never time-out and remain on password prompt. So cannot capture return code.

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -o ConnectTimeout=15 user@ip.ip.ip.ip exit
Enter Windows password:
```

## case-II

When I provide IP address which is not pingable then this approch works.

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -o ConnectTimeout=15 user@ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1 exit   
ssh: connect to host ip1.ip1.ip1.ip1 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Need help in determining if SSH connection is password-less working or not.

Comment: I advise you to do `ssh -v`. That will give you some debug trace about what type of authentication ssh is using (especially if public key on your host are present).

Comment: @Cyrus, Same result..Command never exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable password authentication using `PasswordAuthentication=no`. It will fail immediately, when the pubkey authentication fail.

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=15 user@ip.ip.ip.ip exit
```

Edit: Using `BatchMode` should certainly work.

Comment: awesome , so combination of  PasswordAuthentication and ConnectTimeout is needed!!

Comment: `ConnectionTimeout` is not needed, but it would be helpful, if the server is not reachable.

Comment: So lets try with `BatchMode`. It should do the job. You might have server configured to use `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` (setting that to `no` would help, but `BatchMode` will turn of both of them.

Comment: You are SSH champ :)